# I have created a code that mimics wordle however it does not work as intended

Tags: c

The easiest way to explain my issue is that if the first 2 letters are correct for the first guess, it will always appear as corrected for future guesses even if they are not supposed to. It's like my char string wont reset for each word. I have attached my whole code and was hoping somebody could figure it out. I am working in C code.

This code works by taking a user inputted word (answer) and another user inputted word (guess) then determines if the word guessed has letters in the correct spots (exactly liked wordle). It does this 5 times over or until you guess correctly. If you guess correctly, it will say you won. If you dont guess correctly in the 5 turns it will say you lost.

```
     #include <stdio.h>`enter code here`
        #include <string.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        int main(){

        /* determining variables I will need */
 
            char myWord[6];
            char guess[6];
            char clue[6] = {'x', 'x','x','x','x','\0'};
            float roundsLeft = 5;
            
      /* beginning of game, will not start if the word does not have exactly 5 letters */
           
            printf("please input a secret 5 letter word:\n");
            scanf("%s", &myWord);
            
            if (strlen(myWord) != 5){
                printf ("The target word is not long enough. Please re-run the program.");
            }
        if (strlen(myWord) == 5){
            
 /* while statement which will go over each word and determine letter placements */         
           
 while(roundsLeft!=0 && clue!= "+++++"){
            
            printf("You have %.0f rounds of guessing, please guess a word:\n", roundsLeft);
            scanf("%s", &guess);
            
            if (strcmp(myWord, guess) == 0){
                printf("You win! The word was %s", myWord);
                exit(0);
            }
            
             if (strcmp(myWord, guess) != 0){
                 
            
            printf("%s\n", guess);
            
           
            for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
                if (guess[i] == myWord [i]){
                    clue[i] = '+';
                }
            }
           
            for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
                if (clue[i] == 'x'){
                    for (int j=0; j<5; j++){
                        if (guess[i] == myWord[j] && guess[i] != myWord[i] ){
                            clue[i] = '-';
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
            printf("%s\n", clue);
            
            roundsLeft--;
           
        }  
       
    }
    printf("You've lost. The word was %s", myWord);
        
    }  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `clue!= "+++++"` That's not how strings are compared. Use `strcmp`. You use `strcmp` elsewhere so not sure why you don't here.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you are not overwriting entire clue string for next iteration.

Just add an else condition like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
                if (guess[i] == myWord [i]){
                    clue[i] = '+';
                }
                else{
                    clue[i] = 'x';
                }
            }
```